# issues combining two columns using concat

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issues with combining two columns into the one using mssql

table 1 format:

```
|| WJCPrefix         || WJCNo ||

|| UK-R/SWJC/14/  || 1234  ||

|| UK-R/CUWJC/14/ || 2345  ||

|| UK-R/CUWJC/14/ || 3456  ||

|| UK-R/SWJC/14/  || 4567  ||

|| UK-R/CUWJC/14/ || 5678  ||
```

The desired out would be:

UK-R/CUWJC/14/3456
UK-R/CUWJC/14/5678

the sql statement i am using is:

```
SELECT tblWJCItem.AddedDescription, concat(tblWJC.WJCPrefix, tblWJC.WJCNo)  AS OurRef
FROM tblWJC
INNER JOIN tblWJCItem ON tblWJC.WJCID = tblWJCItem.WJCID;
```

I've also used:

```
SELECT tblWJCItem.AddedDescription, tblWJC.WJCPrefix + '' + tblWJC.WJCNo AS OurRef
FROM tblWJC
INNER JOIN tblWJCItem ON tblWJC.WJCID = tblWJCItem.WJCID;
```

I can't seem to connect these two columns could anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Your column name is Prefix in table, and you are using WJCPrefix which is different in concat(tblWJC.WJCPrefix, tblWJC.WJCNo)

Comment: What results are you getting?  What data type is `tblWJC.WJCNo`?  If it's not a character field, you'll probably need to `CAST(tblWJC.WJCNo AS VARCHAR(X)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query (`Concat()` function) should work if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later.

For other versions, you may need to `Convert()`/`Cast()` `WJCNo` to a string type

```
SELECT t2.AddedDescription, 
       t1.WJCPrefix + CONVERT(Varchar(10),t1.WJCNo) AS OurRef
FROM tblWJC t1
         INNER JOIN tblWJCItem t2 ON t1.WJCID = t2.WJCID;
```

Comment: Thanks Kaf this worked a treat didn't think about having to convert it to a string

Answer (score 0):

Your first query should be fine.  But you might try:

```
SELECT tblWJCItem.AddedDescription, tblWJC.Prefix + cast(tblWJC.WJCNo as varchar(255)) AS OurRef
FROM tblWJC INNER JOIN
     tblWJCItem
     ON tblWJC.WJCID = tblWJCItem.WJCID;
```

You might get an error in the second version if `WJCno` is numeric rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think `WJCNo` is numeric or int field so Convert this field to Varchar first then concat:-

```
SELECT tblWJCItem.AddedDescription, 
       tblWJC.WJCPrefix + '' + CONVERT(Varchar(10),tblWJC.WJCNo) AS OurRef
FROM tblWJC
INNER JOIN tblWJCItem ON tblWJC.WJCID = tblWJCItem.WJCID;
```